# .htaccess - 404 Error Page with RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to enforce all www and http requests to non-www https, and adding the trailing / at the end.

Also, I am redirecting all the requests to index.php from where I am handling the routes.

What I had been doing was, checking for routes url and serving the files in index.php. And, also handling the 404 page from there.

However, I came to know it was not good a way to do it.

I tried doing it with ErrorDocument, but I am facing problem, as I am handling all URL to file thing from index.php and, I am having difficulty in combining RewriteRule  and ErrorDocument.

Also, am I doing this correctly, or if there is any good approach to do it.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# # Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# Adds Trailing slash
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.|^$) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 thisshouldleadtoerrorpage

</IfModule>
```

And this is in the index.php

```
$url_requested = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_len = strlen($url_requested);

$actual_path = substr($url_requested, strpos($url_requested,'/'), $url_len); 

    // HOME PAGE
    if($actual_path == "/"){
        include_once( 'pages/home.php');
    }

Could anyone help me with this.

All I want is a custom 404 page satisfying above conditions. Thanks.
```

Comment: I think the more modern version of this is `FallbackResource`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61117063/231316) for a discussion. Once you hand "not found" off to PHP, however, it is your responsibility (in PHP) to explicitly set a 404 if you really think that should happen

Comment: "I came to know it was not good a way to do it." - What made you think that?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas
1) I was actually having issue in handing the 'not found' 404 to PHP. I think the `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` part was redirecting everything to index.php as 200 OK, so, the ErrorDocument (or FallBackResource) was not getting it. Changing it to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,R=404]` seems to work, but now it was only working for homepage ('/') route.

2) Checking for all routes in the index.php, and from there (if not found): 

else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        include_once( 'pages/404.php');
    }

seems to work. But is it correct way?

Comment: 3) If **2)** was the correct way, I am still confused in one thing. I am also adding rules to add trailing / at the end of the URL. So, if someone goes to **mywebsite.com/eee/**, then they would be getting a 404. However, if someone goes to  **mywebsite.com/eee** then they would first get a 301 redirect for adding **/** and only a 404 after that. So, how is it to deal in such conditions, when I want to give a direct 404 for non-existing routes.

I am sorry if all of this does not make much sense. I am new to PHP and .htaccess thing. So, trying to learn how stuff goes.

Comment: 4) And I am trying to do it for SEO purposes. Which would be the answer for @MrWhite 's question. If I am just giving a simple redirect to the 404 page for non-existing routes, then it would not be a 404 status. (However, I think my **2) ** point addresses that.)

Please let me know if I am overthinking on this :), and it would be a great help, if someone could point me to a right resource.

All I want is my site to redirect all requests to non-www HTTPS with trailing / routes. With custom 404 page. Thanks!!!

Comment: I’m going to reiterate, try `FallbackResource`. Your www and non-secure seem correct. Don’t worry about trailing slash, that’s only for people that type your URLs, your PHP system just has to publish URLs in the form you want. If you let PHP handle content dynamically, you also need to make a [404 page in PHP]. Don’t redirect to it client side, just set the header and send content. You can use an include or a global function or whatever.

Comment: _"if someone goes to mywebsite.com/eee then they would first get a 301 redirect for adding / and only a 404 after that."_ - only your PHP script can determine, whether there actually is content to serve for any requested URL that does not match a physically existing file or folder. So you _can not_ do your trailing-slash-redirect in the .htaccess already, if you want the behavior you described - you would have to do that from within your PHP script as well then.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas Cbroe . Got my answers. And, also the FallbackResource thing seems to work.